# Calling function from outside of component but rendered in v-for loop

Tags: vue.js

I have some component which is rendered 6 times in v-for loop. I'm trying to do onclick function which will call method inside of specified chart component. But now i'm getting errors like this.$refs.chart1.pauseChart() is not an function. This is how i'm trying to achieve it:

```
<BaseChart ref="`chart$[index]`" @click="pauseChart(index)"/>

pauseChart(index) {
  this.$refs.[`chart${index}`].pauseChart()
}
```

Comment: I added an answer as per the code you have and it is working fine. The answer which you accepted will not work as ref should be unique for each child component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ref`s inside `v-for` are arrays rather than singulars. Therefore, if you have

```html
<template v-for="(something, index) in list">
  <BaseChart ref="chart" :key="index" @click="pauseChart(index)" />
</template>
```

you should use

```js
methods:
{
  pauseChart(idx)
  {
    this.$refs.chart[idx].pauseChart();
  }
}
```

For more information - refer to [Vue documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Accessing-Child-Component-Instances-amp-Child-Elements)

Answer (score 0):

`ref` will be having an array. hence, you have to access that with `0` index.

Live Demo **:**

```js
Vue.component('child', {
  methods: {
    pauseChart() {
      console.log('child method call');
    }
  },
  props: ['childmsg'],
  template: '<p v-on="$listeners">{{ childmsg }}</p>',
});

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods: {
    pauseChart(chartIndex) {
      this.$refs[chartIndex][0].pauseChart();
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<div v-for="index in 6" :key="index">
  <child childmsg="Hello Vue!" :ref="`chart${index}`" @click="pauseChart(`chart${index}`)">
  </child>
</div>
</div>
```